# DocuSign error "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign" with proper & valid redirect uri registered in application

Tags: docusignapi

We have docusign integrated in our platform & all of a sudden we are getting error from DocuSign
"The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign".
We have proper & valid redirect uri configured in the application.

Please Note that exsisting setup is working fine, for newer apps or newer accounts, it is throwing the above-mentioned error [Here is the screenshot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAPH8.png) .

The redirect uri is valid as it's working for other app.

Has something changed at DocuSign end recently?

Update:
As asked, Please find the redirect uri screenshots below (I've masked the host url),

[DocuSign Redirect URI configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43RBu.png) - Please note that both URI are same with difference in host url.

[Complete Oauth request url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBe74.png)

[Redirect window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s58Ak.png)

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include the OAuth request URL that you're sending. (It includes the redirectURI.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to compare the URL you see in the browser to the one in the IK. Make sure it's the same IK, in the same env (production vs. developer env is different!). Even a tiny difference between the two URLs will fail this. You need to URL decode the redirecUri from the main URL and then use that by copy/pasting it into the apps and keys page.
Then wait about 1-2 minutes before trying again.

**Edit:** confirmed that the **URLs DO NOT MATCH,** and that is the issue. The URLs must match 100% for this to work

Comment: There are no trailing spaces @Inbar, I've updated my question with screenshots of Oauth redirect url  popup & complete uri as well as redirect configuration at docusign portal.
Please let me know if you find any discrepancies in them. 
I've added the integration & redirect uri days back and it's still not working

Comment: Well, you redacted some of it, so there's no way I can compare the two to make sure you did it right. This error is 100% because the URLs don't match

Comment: Try to change both URLs to something that you can show here and you'll see it works.

Comment: send me an email and I can help you privately - inbar.gazit@docsusign.com

Comment: The redirect uri was not properly configured. Thanks Inbar

Answer (score 0):

Redirect URIs are specific to each integration key (application) and do not get copied over if you make a new integration key. Based on your description it sounds like you have created a new integration key. I would recommend visiting the Apps and Keys page on your DocuSign Admin settings and adding the redirect URI to the new integration key. [Here](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/Redirect-URI-not-registered?language=en_US&rsc_301) is a support centre article which outlines this including the steps for how to add a new redirect URI

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not what i am trying to do. 
Each of my integration(app) has it's own redirect  uri configured. 
It's working for one integration, not for others

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this area has changed on DocuSign AFAIK.

Check that the redirect URI specified in your initial OAuth redirect is the **exact** same as the URI you set in the Integration Key's settings page.

The redirectURI cannot include any dynamic data including query parameters, etc.

You can use the settings tool's Apps and Keys page to delete and then re-add the RedirectURI. Check carefully that it doesn't include any trailing spaces, etc.

After you've made a change via the Apps and Keys pages, wait 5 minutes before attempting to use the Integration Key.

Ensure that you're using the right Apps and Keys page. If your app has passed go-live then:

- For the production systems, use the apps and keys page from docusign.net
- For the developer (demo) system, use the apps and keys page from demo.docusign.net

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots of Oauth redirect url  popup & complete uri as well as redirect configuration at docusign portal.
Please let me know if you find any discrepancies in them.